# Button spacing coming as different in Chrome, firefox and IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css

Since browse button(input control) looked different in these three browsers, I tried to make it look similar by making its opacity 0 and put a dummy button under it and make it look like user is clicking the dummy button(even made sure that browse control is of the same size of that of the dummy button) and it worked fine for IE 11.
When I tested the page in chrome and firefox, there were some spacing issues and also in Firefox, the width I have set for the input control is not working.

```
<input id="Browse" type="file" value="button" style="z-index:12; position:relative; left:0px;opacity:0; width:63px; display:inline-block">
     <asp:button ID="btnBrowse" runat="server" text="Browse" style="z-index:1;        position:absolute;left:595px; height:21.5px"/>
</input>
```

This is what I did. Can some one help me out here!?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to look the same, or at least close, apply a reset style to the button element.

**Reset CSS**

```
input{
    display: inline-block; /* allows margins and padding, but floats like text */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0; /* removes the outline when you click a form element */
}
```

**Styling CSS**

```
input{
    height: 1.5rem;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem; /* same as height - centers vertically */
    color: black;
    background: gray;
}
```

I was styling input fields recently and this should give you a good start.

Comment: Didn't help me at all! :( How do I get this thing to work in firefox? Firefox just doesn't adhere to the width I have given to the control!

Comment: Sorry, I left out a semi colon. But this code works fine for modifying an input field. You may need to modify the code especially if you want to use inline css. Also changing unit measurements.